# Stop creating new thread while system.timers.timer elapsed called

Tags: c#

I am facing a issue when used to system.timers.time, i have a running process in my application.
with timer called my process start, but i want to use that process within the thread only.
because every time timer elapsed event called the new thread has been generated, but i want to prevent this and only using single thread in a process.

Here is my code.

```
Public void Watcher()
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 3000;
    timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
    timer.Enabled = true;
}

Public void OnTimedEvent
{
// process code here
}
```

Here, after every 3 seconds OnTimedEvent called and new thread created, but i don't want to create new thread every time.
So, how to prevent this, any idea?

Comment: use another `Timer` class? anyway, why do you want to prevent it?

Comment: Technically it wont be creating a new thread every time, but acquiring one from the `ThreadPool`. .NET does not use hardware threads but something called [green threads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_threads) and modern (.NET 4.0 and upwards) can support tens of thousands of threads. So, why do you want to prevent the runtime spawning a new thread to handle your callback for you?

Comment: @MindSwipe I suspect the closest thing to Java's _"green threads"_ is `Task` in .NET.  They are a logical abstraction and do not necessarily result in a 1:1 threads.  Not all `Task`s require a thread

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? possible to share the solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a UI you should simply use [forms timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netcore-3.1) or [dispatch timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?view=netcore-3.1). If you do not have a UI you can set the [SynchronizationObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject?view=netcore-3.1) of the timer. This will be responsible for marshaling the execution to the right thread.

I would probably skip the synchronization object, and just do the marshaling in the event handler of the event.

In either case you will need some kind of message loop if you do not have a UI. This would have a threadsafe queue where the thread takes a message and process it, one at a time. For example, using a [blocking collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netcore-3.1) of Action.

As mentioned by @MindSwipe in the comments. A new thread will not be generated per event. It will simply take threads from the threadpool. So the number of threads used should be fairly constant. The main reason for moving all execution to one thread is because it can make threadsafety easier to manage.

Comment: I don't have UI thread, my process is under windows service. so when OnTimedEvent called and found the records process start and it has different managedthreadID and again when records found then process start and it has different managedthreadID. so i want each time when process start then managedthreadID is same like process runs under same thread ID.

Comment: The managed threadID does not matter the slightest. What matters is that that the records processing is threadsafe. One way to do this is to start one thread, and do all processing on that thread, but there are other ways to do it depending on how your application works.